# Increasing hover area for element inside a button

Tags: html, css

http://glymed-plus.mybigcommerce.com/age-management/

On the right side under "in the spotlight" There is a button that says "Shop Now >" and the caret needs to change colors when hovered. If you hover over it you'll see the problem. I want it to change when any area on the button is hovered over, not just the caret.

Here is the code:

```
.spotlights {
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.half {
  width:45%;
  float:left;
}

.spotlight {
 width:45%;
 float:right;
}

.spotlight .btn{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.spotlight .btn:hover{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4ca3c0;
}

.spotlight .btn em{
  color: #4ca3c0;
}

.spotlight .btn em:hover{
  color: #fff;
}

.spot {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #4ca3c0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 98px;
 }

.prodtitle {
  color: #4ca3c0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.spotprod {
  height:190px;
  float:left;
  padding-right: 25px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: please include the relevant html markup in the question itself too please

Comment: I think you have to use JavaScript. If you hover on your Button search for the parent element and change e.g. the background color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to change the color on the button's hover, not the `em`'s hover (which is what you are doing now)

```
.spotlight .btn:hover em{
  color: #fff;
}
```